# Using the Storefront API how can I query for products within a specific collection?

Tags: shopify

I'm reading the [docs](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/reference/products/product) but can't seem to figure out how to query for products within a certain collection.

Here I'm attempting to search my store for collections that have a handle called `nike`. But this doesn't work. The documentation doesn't seem to specify how to search for products within a specified handle:

```
{
    products(first: 10, query:"collections.handle:nike") {
        edges {
            node {
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any to do this? I have tried `collectionsByHandle`, but this is depreciated in recent API versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like so:

```
{
  collection(id:"Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Db2xsZWN0aW9uLzE1MzU3MjUwNzcxOQ==") {
    products(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where the ID is base64 encoded version of this `'gid://shopify/Collection/153572507719'` (where the last part is the id)

[image]

Comment: Since posting I've discovered you can actually do `collection(handle: "all") { ...`, and replace `all` with whatever collection handle.